# How to record webrtc media stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, webrtc, record

everyone.
I want your help.
I am developing sip call app using sip_ua package.
This package doesn't support call recording feature so to do that, I have to use another package or platform-specific API.
I already completed windows package and want to do same feature for mac, android and ios.
Help!

I can find many packages that record microphone but not found any packages that record webrtc media stream. flutter_webrtc package supports MediaRecorder but it is able to use in only web.